# Python-How to write blocks of data in columns?

Tags: python

I have blocks of data that I want to write in a txt, or a csv file. 
These blocks of data are contained as sublists in

```
data=[[('a1','b1'),('c1','d1')],
      [('a2','b2'),('c2','d2'),('e2','f2')],
      [('a3','b3'),('c3','d3'),('e3','f3')]]
```

I want the blocks to appear in sets of columns separated by tabs.
Any ideas?
Thank you,
Jim

Comment: How come the example was removed?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the example because it did not appear formatted and I thought it would seem confusing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure you mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> data=[[('a1','b1'),('c1','d1')],[('a2','b2'),('c2','d2'),('e2','f2')],[('a3','b3'),('c3','d3'),('e3','f3')]]
>>> for columns in izip_longest(*data,fillvalue=''):
        print '\t'.join(map(' '.join,columns))


a1 b1   a2 b2   a3 b3
c1 d1   c2 d2   c3 d3
        e2 f2   e3 f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples) for some examples on how you might go about this. You can define a "tab" however you wish, whether it's 2 or 4 spaces, or whatever suits your applications.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV Module provides a class called "DictWriter" which will do exactly what you are asking for. 
You can have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)